# Permission denied for AD group for NFS directory

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, nfs

I have permission denied problem with NFS share.

On server1 I have `/etc/exports` file with content:

```
/data/test server2.example.com(rw,no_root_squash).
```

`/data/test` directory has 770 permissions with test owner and Active Directory group UnixGroup.

On the server 2 as a UnixGroup AD member I want to cd into `/data/test` mounted directory, but I have permission denied.

fstab file looks:

```
server1:/data/test /data/test nfs4 defaults 0 0
```

What's wrong? Why can't I go into `/data/test` directory as AD group member. Permissions on server 2 are 770 for `/data/test`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.